# OpenSSL 1.0.2m on macOS

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

For building one particular library I need openssl library version 1.0.2m with devel package. I am working on macOS. Using `brew install openssl` installs latest version 1.1.1d.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since OpenSSL 1.0.2 is end of lifed by the end of 2019, it is no longer available via Homebrew. This is mentioned in the [Homebrew 2.2.0 announcement](https://brew.sh/2019/11/27/homebrew-2.2.0/).

It is fairly straightforward to build and install OpenSSL 1.0.2 yourself from source. You can download your required version from the [Old 1.0.2 Releases](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.2/) page and follow the instructions found in [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2m/INSTALL).

---

It may be possible as well to recover an older formula and install from that, but I can not guarantee how well that works. The following steps did complete the installation process:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
$ cd homebrew-core
$ git checkout 75b57384 Formula/openssl.rb
$ brew install Formula/openssl.rb
```

For me, this showed:

```
Warning: openssl 1.1.1d is available and more recent than version 1.0.2m.
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2m.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
```

and went on happily after that. A quick try at the end gives some confidence that it worked out well:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017
```

---

If you prefer not to use `git` directly, you can also try downloading that version of [`openssl.rb` from `gitHub.com`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/75b573845a17aaf3f7c84dc58e97cf5fe39a502b/Formula/openssl.rb) and run `brew install` on it.

---

If you wonder where that commit hash came from, I happened to know that the formula used to be called -- surprise -- `openssl.rb` (but using `git` to query for removed files would have worked as well). Therefore, I inspected the history for `Formula/openssl.rb` and found:

```
$ git log -- Formula/openssl.rb
...
commit 75b573845a17aaf3f7c84dc58e97cf5fe39a502b
Author: BrewTestBot <brew-test-bot@googlegroups.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 2 17:20:33 2017 +0000

    openssl: update 1.0.2m bottle.
```

Comment: It took me forever to reach a working solution - thank you so much for this!

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasted two days on this issue :(

Comment: Using the rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61368160/2551154 is a better solution because it installs as openssl@1.0 and is unlikely to conflict with other packages. Checking out an older version of openssl.rb is likely cause conflicts.

Answer (score 30):

Recently I was struggling due to the recent update in openssl version from 1.0 to 1.1 and wanted to revert it back to older version. No other solution except the one given below worked for me:

`brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p551 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'
gem update --system`

Comment: The first command alone worked for me, although I had to manually fix the symlinks in `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` for it to be picked up.

Comment: amazing. helped me so much!

Comment: @LarsMariusGarshol That works if you don't care about also having OpenSSL 1.1 available.

Comment: I also had to fix the symlinks, I know I will have to come back here the next time MacOS updates, so I will paste the symlink command `ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0 /usr/local/opt/openssl`

Comment: how to you reinstall using rbenv? This line won't work because I'm using rbenv. `rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p551 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'`. please help

Answer (score 13):

Instead of downloading the specific version of `Formula/openssl.rb` you can just use the raw reference to the file with the specific commit SHA as mentioned [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N'-Tricks#installing-directly-from-pull-requests).

So for the last update to version 1.0.2t the SHA is 8b9d6d688f483a0f33fcfc93d433de501b9c3513

```
commit 8b9d6d688f483a0f33fcfc93d433de501b9c3513
Author: BrewTestBot <homebrew-test-bot@lists.sfconservancy.org>
Date:   Sat Sep 28 19:38:49 2019 +0000

    openssl: update 1.0.2t bottle.
```

So I would execute the following command to install 1.0.2t.

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/8b9d6d688f483a0f33fcfc93d433de501b9c3513/Formula/openssl.rb
```

Comment: For me, the command resulted in an error: `"Calling Installation of openssl from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract openssl' to stable tap on GitHub instead."` :/

Answer (score 8):

1- Download the file:

`wget https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb`

2 - Run brew with the file downloaded:

`brew install openssl.rb`

Comment: This worked! I had to first install wget via "brew install wget", which updated a whole lot of packages along the way. I was then able to "brew switch openssl 1.0.2t"

Comment: Additional comment (couldn't edit above as over 5mn). For PHP5.6 (unfortunately still needed on an old project, don't ask), I also had to "wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb" to get icu4c 64.2 and switch to it with "brew switch icu4c 64.2".

Answer (score 8):

Other solutions won't work because you will get this error `"Calling Installation of openssl from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract openssl' to stable tap on GitHub instead."` the following steps will fix it:

1. First go to the local installation of homebrew

```sh
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/
```

2. Homebrew 2.5 remove the option to install formulas directly from git repos so we need to checkout an older version

```sh
git checkout 2.3.0
```

3. Install openssl latest 1.0.x version

```sh
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

4. Go back to current version of homebrew

```sh
git co -
```

5. Tell brew to use the old version of `openssl` this way you can chose wich version to use if you have both intalled

```sh
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
```

Comment: `co` is a common alias for `checkout`. If you haven't set this up please run `git checkout -o` to switch to the current version of homebrew.

Comment: Better solution is just to use: brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0

Answer (score 2):

Update - I think I've been getting downvotes because I've simply posted a link without the solution. So here's the solution:

- Download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap/e472b7861b49cc082d1db0f66f265368da107589/Formula/openssl%401.0.rb) formula for OpenSSL V1.0 (It is patched to work with the arm64 processor)
- Install it `brew install openssl@1.0.rb`
- Add this version to the beginning of your PATH.
  Note: Make sure that RVM is the last PATH variable change in your shell config file (.zshrc / .bashrc)
  `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
- Export some required environment variables

```
 export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.0/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.0/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.0/lib/pkgconfig"
```

- Reload your shell config `source ~/.zshrc`
- Verify your openssl version

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
```

- Disable RVM autolibs `rvm autolibs disable`
- Export some env variables to avoid compilation errors

```
export RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

- Install Ruby

```
rvm install 2.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.0
```

---

[Ref](https://medium.com/@akforsn/installing-old-ruby-versions-on-apple-m1-step-by-step-guide-501bb893c843)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it's not a perfect idea, but it solved my problem (libssl.1.0.0.dylib image not found):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

Hope it works for you!

See [this reply](https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j/issues/48#issuecomment-574391644)

Comment: Don't do this! Using symlinks to system libraries is dangerous. Also new releases of MacOS use LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL. Use: brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0

Answer (score -3):

Here is the linux-brew formula for openssl@1.0.2

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/20ab55b304597c6c47149dc0e50bd5f7ea45b678/Formula/openssl.rb
```