# How to recreate venv with mysql@5.5 with openssl 1.0.0 dependency on mac

Tags: mysql, openssl

I used to have a venv with `mysql@5.5` installed. This somehow broke (I guess because I upgraded my python version) so I'm now trying to recreate it.

However I am getting the following error:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bartjonk/Envs/w-poc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.5/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib Reason: image not found.`

I don't know how to fix it.
I can't do a `brew switch` ore create symlinks as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib), since openssl version  1.0.0 is no longer in my cellar:

```
`> ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/op*         
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 bartjonk  staff    96  2 nov 14:42 .
drwxrwxr-x  106 bartjonk  admin  3392  6 nov 17:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x   14 bartjonk  staff   448  2 nov 14:42 1.1.1h`
```

and `brew install openssl@1.0.0s` or any other variants (`brew install openssl@1.0` etc.) only result in :

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "openssl@1.0.2s".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Did you see this question: [OpenSSL 1.0.2m on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337838/openssl-1-0-2m-on-macos)?

Comment: Thanks, @ReinierTorenbeek, works like a charm. I upgraded your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the comment given by [@Reinier Torenbeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380680/reinier-torenbeek) (answer to: [OpenSSL 1.0.2m on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337838/openssl-1-0-2m-on-macos)) works like a charm.

I can now switch between the old and the new implementation using:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2m
```

You can check which versions are available using:

```
ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/op*
```

Comment: Since you asked for `1.0.2s` originally, did you notice that the answer also shows how you could go about installing that one (as opposed to `1.0.2m`)?

Comment: Hi @ReinierTorenbeek, yes I did! Thx.